# custom ListView strange behavoiur

Tags: android, listview, customization

everyone.
I have a strange behaviour of my custom `ListView`

[image]

`ListView` dividers longer than `ListView`. Anyone can help me?

This is my layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/back_button_color" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.93"
            android:text="@string/messages"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_message_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/back_button_color"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/compose" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/dialog_list" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and list_row file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white_color" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ava_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ava_background" />





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_intelocutor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ava_image"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_body"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_intelocutor"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_intelocutor"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />







        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/online_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name_intelocutor"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name_intelocutor"
            android:src="@drawable/online_list" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the width attribute of ListView to fill_parent.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/dialog_list" >

</ListView>
```

Change it to wrap content,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/dialog_list" >

</ListView>
```

Changing the margins and paddings in **list_row.xml** will not affect the divider length since it considers that your list occupies the entire width of the screen.

Comment: thank you for reply, but changing `layout_width` to `wrap_content` give the same result.

Comment: do u really need to show divider? you can just remove it if u want.

Comment: if i remove divider ListView still doesn't fill screen width

Comment: Did u try removing this attribute android:layout_gravity="left" from your listview?

Comment: thank you once again for replies. i'm find solution. problem was in `android:listSelector="@drawable/dialog_list"` if moving this to row layout program works fine